# How can I edit an attribute?

Tags: python

I would like to print out these results with my code:

```
{'name': 'asm0', 'size': '1024000'}
{'name': 'asm1', 'size': '1024000'}
{'name': 'asm2', 'size': '1024000'}
```

But it appears like this..

```
{'name': 'asm0', 'size': '1024000'}
{'name': 'asm01', 'size': '1024000'}
{'name': 'asm012', 'size': '1024000'}
```

Please see my sample code below and let me know how can I fix it..

```
#-----------------------------------
!/usr/bin/python
vdisks = {
    "name": "asm",
    "size": "1024000"
}

for i in range(3):
    new_vdisks = vdisks
    new_vdisks["name"] = vdisks["name"] + str(i)
    print new_vdisks

#-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You are editing the same `dict` every time. And every time you add your iteration number to `"name"` value.

You can make a [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) of it.

```
from copy import copy

for i in range(3):
    new_vdisks = copy(vdisks)
    new_vdisks["name"] = vdisks["name"] + str(i)
    print new_vdisks
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of `vdisks["name"]` each time you pass through the for loop.

It starts off as "asm" then you add 0 to it, then you add 1 during the next iteration, and finally 2 in the third.

You can create a new variable to store the original value and add that instead:

```
vdisks = {
    "name": "asm",
    "size": "1024000"
}

name = vdisks["name"]

for i in range(3):
    new_vdisks = vdisks
    new_vdisks["name"] = name + str(i)
    print new_vdisks
```

Because it never passes through the `for` loop the new variable never changes from `asm` giving your expected output.

Comment: No problem whatsoever.  Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#-----------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/python
vdisks = {
    "name": "asm",
    "size": "1024000"
}

for i in range(3):
   vdisks["name"] = "asm"
   new_vdisks = vdisks
   new_vdisks["name"] = vdisks["name"] + str(i)
   print new_vdisks

#-----------------------------------
```

Comment: It is not necessary to re-write `vdisk["name"]` each time.  Although this works, if the value of `name` changes this will need to be re-written, although there is nothing wrong with this, I think reading without overwriting twice is a much better idea.